# Maximize linear objective with nonlinear constraint

Tags: matlab, optimization

I would like to solve a maximization problem involving a linear objective function and nonlinear constraint.  In particular, my problem is:

```
max_x f(x) = c_1x_1
s.t. g_m(x) <= 0 for m = 1,...,M
g_m(x) = 0 for m = M+1,...,N
x in X
```

where X is a compact subset of a finite dimensional euclidean space.  One way to solve this is to use the `fmincon` function in `MatLab`.  To do this, we call

```
fmincon(@(x)linobj(x,c),x0,[],[],[],[],lx,ux,nonlinear_constraint,options_fmincon);
```

where `linobj(x,c)` is the linear function

```
function [val,gradient] = linobj(x,c)
% c is a vector with c = (c_1,0,0,...,0)'
val = dot(x,c)
if nargout > 1
    gradient = [c(1) 0 0 ... 0].'
end
end
```

`nonlinear_constraint` is a function of `x` that computes the inequality and equality constraint values at `x` and the gradients, and `ux` and `lx` specifies the boundary of `X`.

I understand that there are fast methods of computing the `argmax` to a problem that has linear/quadratic objective function with linear/quadratic constraints (e.g., by using `CVXGEN`).  So my question is this: Given the particular structure of this problem, is there a faster way of computing the `argmax` of this problem (relative to `fmincon`) in `Matlab`?  In particular, can I use the fact that my objective function is linear to speed up computation?

Comment: In the general case (arbitrary nonlinear constraints), there really isn't much structure in the problem you've posed. If your constraints are convex, then yes, there are solvers (both built into MATLAB and as external libraries that can be called from within MATLAB) that can do this faster than `fmincon`. But what solver to use depends on the what kind of constraints they are (linear vs. quadratic vs. second-order cone vs. semidefinite cone etc).

Comment: I think you are asking for a solver that is specialized to handle problems with a linear objective and general non-linear constraints. Sorry, to my knowledge there is no such beast. You will have to use a general purpose NLP solver such as `fmincon`.

Comment: For my problem, the constraint set is not necessarily convex, but it is twice continuously differentiable.  Therefore, I should use `MultiStart` with `fmincon`.